# Microsoft word slow switching and safe mode

Tags: microsoft-word, safe-mode

I don't know what I did, but recently when I opened Microsoft Word document, I experienced very slow app switch between it and other applications. When I start Word in Word's safe mode (as described here http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/troubleshootin1/qt/safemode.htm ), the issue disappears. Now I don't know where to find out which plugins were loaded that's causing the problem. Or where the normal.dot is if that's the problem. I'm on Windows 7 64 bit. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm using Office 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Endnote is the problem and it's documented on Endnote web site.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting any addins in this path

```
%programfiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\STARTUP
```

and

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP
```

Comment: Both folders are empty to begin with. :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The answer was taken from [this forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/office-2013-only-works-in-safe-mode/84c96e77-2148-474e-8c5d-8407897c65d2)

To fix de problem, you must disable hardware acceleration

1. Run regedit (Win + R ; "regedit")
2. Browse to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common**
3. Create a New Key and name it "**`Graphics`**"
4. Select Graphics, right-click on the right panel and create a New **`DWORD (32-bit) Value`** and name it **`DisableHardwareAcceleration`**.
5. Enter Value data as `1`

Try to run Word/Excel normally now.